# Meteor Tracker autorun fires 2 times

Tags: meteor

This Meteor client code tries to make the `Tracker.autorun` to run once but as it appears to be that it has to run twice, once for setting and once for reactiveness.
Which is fine but it is firing 3 times. Once for setting and 2 for reacting even though the server only updated the `user.profile.abc` once.

To test it, I run this code in the mongodb console and the the iamge attached is what I got which confirms it fires twice.

How can I get it to run only once for responding to the changes in the users collection? Thanks

```
db.users.update({_id: Meteor.userId()},{$set: {'profile.ABC': ['a','b']}}).pretty()
```

[image]

```
//client
Meteor.call('cleanABC', (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    ABCListener();
  }
});

ABCListener: () => {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      console.log('auto run invoked');
      if (Meteor.user().profile.ABC) {
        const myArray = Meteor.user().profile.ABC;
        //myFunction(myArray);
        console.log('condition true');
      } else {
        console.log('condition false');
      }
    }
  });
}

//server
'cleanABC': function() {
  return Meteor.users.update({
    _id: Meteor.userId()
  }, {
    $unset: {
      'profile.ABC': ''
    }
  });
}

//and some where else in the code
  Meteor.users.update({
  _id: userId
}, {
  $set: {
    'profile.ABC': myArray
  }
}, (err) => {
  if (!err) {
    console.log('just sent the array');
  }
});
```

Comment: Meteor user is reactive. Do you need Tracker.autorun for this?

Comment: @Vijay you mean just use the `profile.ABC` right away. Humm, I will have to think how to.

Comment: Yes. Another thing to keep in mind is the update is instantaneously applied on minimongo. Then with some latency, the same code runs on server. If there is any difference between minimongo and Mongo, minimongo is synced with the update. Tracker might also be called if there is an update to profile from server push.

Comment: @Vijay event when I use it right out the box with out the `Tracker.autorun`, it still fires twice. I use the array inside a template helper

Comment: Can you look at your dev console to see if you are getting two updates being sent on the DDP? In Chrome you can see this in the Network tab -> WS (at the top).  If you are seeing two DDP requests, I would then check what happens when you update the user directly in Mongo.  If you still see two, then it's something in the publish.  If you don't, then at least you would know to focus more on the client-side.

Comment: @CodeChimp it appears to be on the client in this case.

Comment: Then I would favor the response from Vijay in that, when saving data on the client-side, you can really end up with 2 updates in the client's minimongo.  I think the most widely used pattern for updating data on the server is to use Meteor methods and do the insert on the server directly, and not the client, when possible.  Obviously there are cases where that is not true, but when updating user info I would lean more towards the Meteor methods pattern.  This way the Meteor method can validate the input and perform any ACLs without showing the code to the client at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are just calling Tracker.autorun everytime you call the method.

I think if you change your client code to:

```
//client
  ABCListener: () => {
  Tracker.autorun(() => {
    if (Meteor.userId()) {
      console.log('auto run invoked');
      if (Meteor.user().profile.ABC) {
        const myArray = Meteor.user().profile.ABC;
        //myFunction(myArray);
        console.log('condition true');
      } else {
        console.log('condition false');
      }
    }
  });
}
Meteor.call('cleanABC');
```

it should work.

Comment: Good looking out!  `Tracker.autorun` is a tricky beast to get working.  I think that's why there were rumors that MDG was removing it from the API docs and not publicly advertising it's existence anymore.  I know every time I have had to use it for something I have had to stop pretending I know how it works and just accept the fact someone way more intelligent than me came up with it.

Comment: Good looking out!  `Tracker.autorun` is a tricky beast to get working.  I think that's why there were rumors that MDG was removing it from the API docs and not publicly advertising it's existence anymore.  I know every time I have had to use it for something I have had to stop pretending I know how it works and just accept the fact someone way more intelligent than me came up with it.